# Flex Event Handling

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, dispatchevent

Folks,

I had a doubt in Flex's event handling and dispatching mechanism.

Consider the below diagram,

Both Panels i.e `Panel1` and `Panel2` are under the same application.

[image]

I want to dispatch an event on click on `Send` Button, and be able to listen for that event by adding event listener on `Receive` Button.

How can I do that ?

PS : Since, AFAIK, `dispatchEvent` only dispatches event ***up the Parent Hierarchy***. Is that right ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't. Event Handling mechanism of Flex (actually it is Flash, Flex adds nothing) is an implementation of Observer Pattern, which allows the Observer to invoke a specific function (eventListener) when there's some change inside the host component (event is being dispatched). Adding an eventListener to `Receive` button to watch for changes of `Send` button breaks the fundamental rule of OOP.

P.S: I always avoid to use `bubble` mechanism when possible. It's not good to manage code later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. But if you really want to handle events cross views or components without adding too many dependencies, I suggest you take advantage of frameworks like Parsley and their messaging features.

http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/

Comment: looks like sgokhales took your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Events originate from a component and bubble upwards (child to parent), never downwards (parent to child) or sideways (sibling to sibling).

You can instead have an event listener in the parent application, which will invoke some function in panel 2 when it receives the event from panel 1

Comment: -1 - You have a bit of misinformation in your response: Events have a capturing stage first, which does actually propagate from Application down to the target.  The bubbling phase occurs after this and that propagates up (target to Application).  However, you are still correct that the siblings can't capture on this phase either.

Answer (score 0):

> adding event listener on Receive Button

There's something wrong here. Add event listener in button code? Is it custom button? Even if so, button should not process events - it should be a simple building block dispatching its own click events and not concerning with anything else.
What you really seem to need is notify one component of another's activity. You can just "use Parsley" like kyohiro suggests, or make your own connector, like this:

```
public class MessageBus extends EventDispatcher {
    //singleton facility
    private static _instance:MessageBus;

    public static get instance():MessageBus {
        if (!_instance) _instance = new MessageBus();
        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Then you use this MessageBus to add event listener to it (Panel2) and dispatch events through it (Panel1). This way Panel1 doesn't know about Panel2, they only know both MessageBus. So, to connect two components, you only need unique String constant for each event.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest but bad practise is parentApplication.addEventListener and parentApplication.dispatchEvent . 
For this You should use global static dispatcher class .